# How i can group this query?

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I want group by order.orderID.
is it possible?
I try but I cant do it.
Any ideas?

```
   var query = from order in mydb.Orders

                     join customer in mydb.Customers on order.CustomerID equals customer.CustomerID
                     join employee in mydb.Employees on order.EmployeeID equals employee.EmployeeID
                     join shipper in mydb.Shippers on order.ShipVia equals shipper.ShipperID
                     join orderdetail in mydb.Order_Details on order.OrderID equals orderdetail.OrderID
                     join product in mydb.Products on orderdetail.ProductID equals product.ProductID
                     select new
                                 {

                                     OrderID = order.OrderID,
                                     CustomerName = customer.CompanyName,
                                     EmployeeName = employee.FirstName,
                                     ShipperName = shipper.CompanyName,
                                     Products = product.ProductName,
                                     TotalPrice = orderdetail.UnitPrice * orderdetail.Quantity
                                 };
```

Comment: Group *what* by `orderId`?

Comment: @Richard group repeat data

Comment: What data? `customer`, `employee`, … or something else? There are many items of data in you example code. Be explicit in terms of that code, otherwise we have to guess.

Comment: There is nothing called `all` in your code.. Make it easy for people to answer you question, your getting help for free so put some effort in.

Comment: @Richard I want group customer,employee, shipper, orderdetail and product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `group by` clause to the end of your expression via a *query continuation*:

```
var query = from order in mydb.Orders
            join customer in mydb.Customers on order.CustomerID equals customer.CustomerID
            […]
            select new {
              OrderID = order.OrderID,
              CustomerName = customer.CompanyName,
              […]
            }
            into result
            group result by result.OrderId;
```

Comment: it's good. but I get errors in displaying data
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299708/a-problems-with-display-data-from-linq-queries-in-grid

Comment: @user4523894 see my answer to that question. *But* please define, clearly, in that question, what your requirements are *with an example*, until then your intentions are unclear.