# A problems with display data from linq queries in grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I make this query. LinqSQl

```
         var query = from order in mydb.Orders
                    join customer in mydb.Customers on order.CustomerID    equals customer.CustomerID
                    join employee in mydb.Employees on order.EmployeeID equals employee.EmployeeID
                    join shipper in mydb.Shippers on order.ShipVia equals shipper.ShipperID
                    join orderdetail in mydb.Order_Details on order.OrderID equals orderdetail.OrderID
                    join product in mydb.Products on orderdetail.ProductID equals product.ProductID
                    select new
                                 {
                                     OrderID = order.OrderID,
                                     CustomerName = customer.CompanyName,
                                     EmployeeName = employee.FirstName,
                                     ShipperName = shipper.CompanyName,
                                     Products = product.ProductName,
                                     TotalPrice = orderdetail.UnitPrice * orderdetail.Quantity

                                 }
                        into d
                        group d by d.OrderID;
```

then I want display this data in datagrid

there is my markup:

```
              <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="asp1._Default" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head id="Head1" runat="server">
 </head>
  <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
     <asp:GridView ID="Grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  
           CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"  Width="600px">
        <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderID" HeaderText="Name" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerName" HeaderText="CustomerName" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeName" HeaderText="EmployeeName" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="ShipperName" HeaderText="ShipperName" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="Products" HeaderText="Products" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalPrice" HeaderText="TotalPrice" />
        </Columns>   
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#7961da"  Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />         
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3"  ForeColor="#333333" />
      </asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
</body>
 </html>
```

thus method

```
         Grid.DataSource = query.ToList();
         Grid.DataBind();
```

And I get error: A field or property with the name 'OrderID' was not found on the selected data source.

What is my problem?

because when I use this query

```
  var query1 = from order in mydb.Orders
                     join customer in mydb.Customers on order.CustomerID    equals customer.CustomerID
                     join employee in mydb.Employees on order.EmployeeID equals employee.EmployeeID
                     join shipper in mydb.Shippers on order.ShipVia equals shipper.ShipperID
                     join orderdetail in mydb.Order_Details on order.OrderID equals orderdetail.OrderID
                     join product in mydb.Products on orderdetail.ProductID equals product.ProductID

                     select new
                     {

                         OrderID = order.OrderID,
                         CustomerName = customer.CompanyName,
                         EmployeeName = employee.FirstName,
                         ShipperName = shipper.CompanyName,
                         Products = product.ProductName,
                         TotalPrice = orderdetail.UnitPrice * orderdetail.Quantity
                     };
                                 Grid.DataSource = query1;
                                 Grid.DataBind();
```

I display data, but they aren't grouped.

I get this data

```
OrderId| CustomerName| EmployeeName |ShipperName | Products| TotalPrice

1          Apple        Kevin            AIG        Iphone     1000

1          Apple        Kevin            AIG        IPAD     1100

2         Samsung          John           KMP        S6       900

2         Samsung          John           KMP        S5       800
```

I want to get this result.

```
OrderId| CustomerName| EmployeeName |ShipperName | Products   | TotalPrice

1          Apple        Kevin            AIG       Iphone,Ipad     2100

2         Samsung          John           KMP        S6,s5       1700
```

Comment: Is this markup all you have for the grid view?

Comment: With that gridview markup, i wonder if you ever found answer. Care to define some fields in markup?

Comment: @husnain_sys There is mu full markup

Comment: @Andrei I add my markup

Comment: Your markup is not right. Add some fields to gridview which will hold values of your query. See that links for clarification http://asphelps.com/GridView/How-to-bind-GridView-by-using-Linq.aspx

Comment: @husnain_sys thanks. I edit my markup and I get new error. Also, I edit question

Comment: Try "order by" instead of "group by"

Comment: @maxim.tkachenko,
Unfortunately, its not solution. Because, orderby only sort data. I want to group/join it repeat data. For example, the query1 get me this list
1 K
1 K
1 K
2 L
2 L
But I want to get 1 K
2 L
Orderby don't gives me this result

Comment: Make ToDictionary instead of grouping and render markup manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `group by` in the LINQ expression it changes the type of the result from `IEnumerable<AnonType>` to `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, AnonType>>` as `OrderID` apears to be a `int` (see the documentation for the method `group by` uses on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

Thus you cannot just display as a simple list of the anonymous type.

If you want to order the results by `OrderId` then `group by` is a waste of time: use `order by` to sort.

If you want to process all objects for each `OrderID` then you need to group.

***Edit*** **based on amended question:**

Before displaying the data, it appears you want to sum up the runs by `OrderId`, specically:

- Sum up `TotalPrice`
- Join the `Prodcts` with comma separators.

This is easy enough to do, but will mean creating new instances. Starting with `groupedData` from previous query:

```
var outputData = groupedData.Select(g => new {
                                      OrderId = g.Key,
                                      […]
                                      Products = String.Join(", ", g.Select(x => x.Products)),
                                      TotalPrice = g.Select(x => x.TotalPrice).Sum()
                                    });
```

Each object from the `group by` is a `IGrouping<int, AnonType>` which is an `IEnumerable<AnonType>` with an additional `Key` property (what it is grouped by); thus can use the usual LINQ operators to perform the aggregations.

Comment: @user4523894 So you need to process your (grouped) data from the LINQ query before processing it further. I'll add some notes on that.

Comment: @user4523894 **NB** on the previous question I said you needed to state you requirements: this is why, only when you show what problem you are trying to solve can we get close to an answer.